# How to grant permission in RESTful API to user in Netbackup 8.1.1?

Tags: backup, symantec

I have account in Netbackup Java console and commandline with all permissions, but in REST api, I can only access part of resources like /appdetails.  To other path like /admin/jobs, I got following error: 
`{"errorCode":8000,"errorMessage":"User does not have permission(s) to perform the requested operation."}`

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the Netbackup master server and perform the following steps.

1. /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpnbaz -setupExAudit
2. /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpnbaz -AddUser domainType:master_server:User
3. /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/bpnbat -addUser User User_pwd master_server
4. /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpnbaz -listusers
   Number of users with NetBackup Administrator Privileges: 1

   Domain Type : domainType
   Domain      : master_server
   Username    : User

   Operation completed successfully.
5. /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpnbaz -DisableExAudit
6. Restart Netbackup services

Domain Type:

Unixpwd - UNIX Password file on the Authentication server

WINDOWS - Primary Domain Controller or Active Directory